# Move a persistent USB Ubuntu to a smaller USB drive

Tags: live-usb, persistence, clonezilla

I plan to move my persistent USB Ubuntu which is currently on a 32GB USB drive (limited to only 4GB by default) to a new 4GB USB drive. I'm thinking of using Clonezilla to do this. Is this the best option for the task? They also mentioned that **"the destination partition must be equal or larger than the source one."**
Would the copying work in my case then?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the `casper-rw` file from one USB drive to the other.

`casper-rw` is the name of the file where the Live USD stores persistent information.

Since the size of then`casper-rw` file itself is 4GB, and Ubuntu will require an additional GB or so, you'll need a larger USB drive, say 8GB.